# "Changes must be made through a pull request" even though user is in "Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests" list

Tags: github, permissions, github-pages, package.json, cicd

Im implementing a workflow where one of the jobs is to increment the package.json version.
For this, im using a GH action.

One Problem is that the new version should be updated in a protected branch `development`.

To bypass it, ive add 1 user (`test-user`) to `Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests`

The github action accepts user name and email to config before writing the to package.json
Even after allowing this user to bypass and passing the name and email to the action, im getting:

`Changes must be made through a pull request. 5 of 5 required status checks are expected. You're not authorized to push to this branch.`

What am i missing?

Comment: You'll have to show us the contents of your GitHub Action.  It's likely that the operation you're performing isn't made with the user in question, but we can't know without seeing the YAML file.